# Setting properties of a node from a csv - Neo4j

Tags: csv, neo4j

This is an example of my csv file:

```
_id,official_name,common_name,country,started_by,
ABO.00,Association Football Club Bournemouth,Bournemouth,England,"{""day"":NumberInt(1),""month"":NumberInt(1),""year"":NumberInt(1899)}"
AOK.00,PAE Kerkyra,Kerkyra,Greece,"{""day"":NumberInt(30),""month"":NumberInt(11),""year"":NumberInt(1968)}"
```

I have to import this csv into Neo4j:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 
'file:///Z:/path/to/file/team.csv' as line
create (p:Team {_id:line._id, official_name:line.official_name, common_name:line.common_name, country:line.country, started_by_day:line.started_by.day,started_by_month:line.started_by.month,started_by_year:line.started_by.year
```

I get an error(*Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidType*) setting `started_by.day, started_by.month, started_by.year`
How can I set rightly the properties about started_by?

Answer (score 1):

Format of you csv should be following:

```
_id,official_name,common_name,country,started_by_day,started_by_month,started_by_year
ABO.00,Association Football Club Bournemouth,Bournemouth,England,1,1,1899
```

Cypher:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Z:/path/to/file/team.csv' as line
CREATE (p:Team {_id:line._id, official_name:line.official_name, common_name:line.common_name, country:line.country, started_by_day:line.started_by_day,started_by_month:line.started_by_month,started_by_year:line.started_by_year})
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your date part in the csv file is in JSON format - don't you need to parse that first?

`line.started_by`

is this string

```
"{""day"":NumberInt(30),""month"":NumberInt(11),""year"":NumberInt(1968)}"
```

There is no `line.started_by.day`